# iFrame not allowing me to click buttons

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a iFrame showing a pdf inside a simple popup "control". When you click the link it should open and display the pdf inside the iFrame, however, this does not seem to work in Google Chrome when there is a valid pdf file to display. The popup works 100% if the pdf it is sourced to doesn't exist or if I am sourcing a webpage, then it works, but if I want to show the pdf, it doesn't work. Can anyone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it? I have the code in a fiddle here.

```
code
```

[Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/JkEsr/2/)

Please note the code does work in this fiddle but that is only because the pdf I sourced to doesn't exist in this case. I couldn't find a sourcable pdf to use as test data.

Comment: Opening PDF's in browser depends on the clients set-up, they must have a PDF reader installed in their browser..

Comment: I do have it installed, I can view pdfs without the popup. And the popup works for the first click, afterwards it seems like it disables the button

Comment: i'd using chrome, and i added a pdf into your code: http://jsfiddle.net/JkEsr/3/ works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to add full address to PDF file. I added: http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf

It works fine for me on Chrome Version 28.0.1500.95, Mac OS X 10.8

Comment: okay.. well it worked for me too now, but then why would it not work when its running from my local host? its a copy and paste code so they're 100% identical

Comment: Add a full address to your file as src attr. e.g. http:://localhost/my/pdf/file.pdf

Comment: That didn't work for me. I even made a smaller iframe to see if the pdf is coming through right, and it is. So using the full path doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give an absolute path position in order for it to work:

e.g. http://www.website.com/files/news.pdf instead of /files/news.pdf